# Search for values in dictionaries within dictrionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, search

I am quite new to python and wondering if there is an easy way to find a value for a specific key for dictionaries within dictionaries. I am sure you could write a loop etc but wondering if there is a more direct way especially if there are multiple layers and you don't know upfront where exactly the value sits?

Let's say if I like to find the value for 'Mother'

```
a = {'family 1':{'Father':'Joe', 'Mother': 'Eva'}}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `a["family 1"]["Mother"]`

Comment: You could write a function and name it `recursive_lookup`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def recursive_lookup(d, key):
    if key in d:
        return d[key]
    for v in d.values():
        if not isinstance(v, dict):
            continue
        x = recursive_lookup(v, key)
        if x is not None:
            return x
    return None
```

This can be used as follows:

```
>>> d = {'family 1': {'Father': 'Joe', 'Mother': 'Eva'}}
>>> recursive_lookup(d, "Mother")
'Eva'
```

Comment: Thanks - makes sense. I was more wondering if there is built-in function which does this